# Svelte store value from async script in variable

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, svelte

I'm new to svelte so maybe I'm missing something obvious. I want to use OAuth2 in my Svelte application. There is no npm package, so, I need to load it by using a regular `<script>`. I want to retrieve the user from the Google api and display it in a variable in my component. Currently I'm loading the script in a `<svelte:head>` component and this works fine. Here is my working code:

```
<svelte:head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function init() {
      gapi.load("auth2", function () {
        gapi.auth2
          .init({
            clientId: "my_clientId",
            apiKey: "my_apiKey",
          })
          .then(() => {
            GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(); // Create instance
            if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) { // If signed in, log name
              const profile = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
              console.log("Full Name: " + profile.getName());
            } else { // Else trigger login
              GoogleAuth.signIn();
            }
          });
      });
    }
  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

This code will `console.log` the username if the user is logged in, otherwise it will trigger a google login popup.

How would I store the user profile retrieved from GoogleAuth in a variable in my Svelte component instead of just logging it? I have tried [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629947/how-do-i-load-an-external-js-library-in-svelte-sapper) and also tried to pass an `on:load={}` function to my `svelte:head>` as shown [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/28f4b2e36e4244b8b23cae3d584c4c88?version=3.16.6).

Comment: Have you tried to use a [svelte store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores)? You can store the user profile and then get it again in an another file in a reactive way.

Comment: @johannchopin That's exactly what I would like to do. But the function I'm using right now is in the `<svelte:head>`. I don't think that I can access the store from within the `svelte:head>`.

Comment: Yeah you're right actually it doesn't work. But what is the goal to put this function in the `head` actually?

Comment: @johannchopin I need to wait for the gapi package to load first. After it has loaded I can validate the current user. The only way I could wait for the package to load and then validate the user was by putting the function in the head and then call a the init function when it's loaded. If there is a way to do this without putting the function in the `head` that would be fine.

Comment: Sure you could just do it on Mount of your entry svelte component. Just wait for this function before doing everything else.

Comment: @johannchopin That's exactly what I would like to do. But I don't know how to wait for this function. That's why I declared the function in the `head`. But I want to be able to wait for gapi to load and then call a function outside of the `head` so that I can access my store and env variables

Comment: You just need to render your app when the api call is done. This could be easily achieved using a `if/else` logic. Check this REPL that reproduce this behaviour https://svelte.dev/repl/43f560381dd043f3801fb8981c16d573?version=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function after the script in the `<svelte:head>` is loaded it is possible to call a function with `on:load`. Make sure to call this function with parentheses, like this: `on:load="{yourFunction()}"` and not `on:load="{yourFunction}"` (this is wat I did wrong).

The final code looked like this:

```
<script>
  function init() {
    gapi.load("auth2", function () {
      gapi.auth2
        .init({
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
          apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        })
        .then(() => {
          const GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
          if (!GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            if (window.location.pathname !== "/login") {
              window.location.href = "/login";
            }
          }
        });
    });
  }
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script
    src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"
    async
    defer
    on:load="{init()}">
  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

The init function is now in a regular script tag. We could also access the svelte store from here.

Answer (score 1):

inside `<script>` block include the `init` function

```
<script>

window.gauthinit = ()=>{
 gapi.load("auth2", function () {
        gapi.auth2
          .init({
            clientId: "my_clientId",
            apiKey: "my_apiKey",
          })
          .then(() => {
            GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(); // Create instance
            if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) { // If signed in, log name
              const profile = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
              console.log("Full Name: " + profile.getName());

              ////DO SAVE DATA IN STORES
 
            } else { // Else trigger login
              GoogleAuth.signIn();
            }
          });
      });

}

</script>
```

in `<svelte:head>` change to this

```
<svelte:head>
  <script
    src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=gauthinit"
    async
    defer>

  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: This works! I did have to put the function in an `onMount` but it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: So, I thought this worked. But I guess there was something cached in the browser which made it work. If I place place the code in the `<script>` tag it does run, but I get an error `window is undefined`. I tried moving it to `onMount`, but then the function does not run at all.