# Adding JS from HTML Template in Sveltekit project

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have an HTML Template with CSS and JS. I wanted to import it in SvelteKit.

Adding HTML and CSS is pretty straightforward. When it comes to JS, there are problems.

As far as I have tested with the browser, The imported JS code works, but it fails to affect the DOM.
Ex. console.log works, but adding bootstrap.js or slick.js do not work. Also, custom JS written is not loading. This means there is no issue with the directory.

This is how I have imported CSS and JS in Svelte.

```
<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/responsive.css" />
    
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

Is there another way to import external JS to Svelte files, a way where the JS will affect the DOM?

Comment: May find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629947/how-do-i-load-an-external-js-library-in-svelte-sapper

Comment: I would directly place any scripts into app.html if these are global.

Answer (score 0):

For global scripts, you can add them to your `app.html` or `index.html` in your SvelteKit project, just like how you would with a normal HTML webpage:

`src/app.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- Metadata such as title or description -->
        <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <!-- Your CSS / JS globally -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://some-cdn.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://some-cdn.com/js/script.js"></script>
        %sveltekit.head%
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>%sveltekit.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HOWEVER**, it seems you're importing them from an absolute URL. If this is located inside the `/lib` folder, you can import them using a  tag in your `+layout.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import "$lib/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    // you can do the same with JavaScript    
</script>
```

A very common scenario, however, is that they are in `node_modules`. To import these, you can import them from the module:

```
<script>
    import "module/style.css"
</script>
```

If they are in your `static` folder, you can use app.html to import them as shown in the first example.

Since you're using bootstrap, I would recommend to use [svelte-add/bootstrap](https://github.com/svelte-add/bootstrap) and import any necessary JS in app.html using a CDN